# How to force numpy to treat it's elements as an object

Tags: python, numpy

I have a library that connects me to a certain database and as one of the options to store data I have an array. The library is coded in such a way that I cannot use n-dimensional arrays.

Let's say I want to store some number of int32's. I would do this:

```
np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int32)
```

Let's say I want to store some number of arrays of doubles
I could do this:

```
np.array([np.array([1., 2., 3.]), np.array([4., 5.])], dtype=object)
```

Because the result doesn't yield n-dimensional arrays but an array of arrays:

```
array([array([1., 2., 3.]), array([4., 5.])], dtype=object)
```

However, whenever I make all of the arrays the same shape:

```
np.array([np.array([1., 2., 3.]), np.array([4., 5., 6.])], dtype=object)
```

The result is:

```
array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
       [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]], dtype=object)
```

And I wanted:

```
array([array([1., 2., 3.]), array([4., 5., 6.])], dtype=object)
```

because that's what the library would accept. I understand why numpy does that optimization, however I want to overrite it.

Comment: the real question is then: why are you using numpy at all? why not use something like a list? NumPy with `dtype=object` is considered bad, because you lose all the performance optimizations that you could have gained. Now you're going one step further and converting a ndarray to essentially a list (the only advantage of ndarray is faster slicing for object type), meaning you get no more meaningful benefits.

Comment: @EpicCoder the library requires it to be a numpy array

Comment: @TimRoberts I do not want to create a 2D array but an array of arrays

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @hpaulj:

Creating an empty array of objects and then assigning elements to arrays works:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.empty((2,), object)
array[0] = np.array([1., 2., 3.])
array[1] = np.array([4., 5., 6.])

print(array)
```

gives:

```
array([array([1., 2., 3.]), array([4., 5., 6.])], dtype=object)
```

UPDATE:
Since a some of the comments mentioned it, I want to include it here as well. To set all of the elements at once you can do:

```
array[:] = list(np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]]))
```

Comment: If you have many rows to assign: `array[:] = list(np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]], dtype=object))`

Comment: @mozway That way, I instead get `[array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype=object) array([4.0, 5.0, 6.0], dtype=object)]`. Do you not?

Comment: @Kelly I think it's what OP wants (an array or arrays). (If your remark was about the dtype of the inner arrays and an int/float dtype is wanted, then `array[:] = list(np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]]))`, which is the same logic)